# osx conda install boost compiled with gcc

Tags: macos, boost, conda

I'm trying to install [boost using anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/boost) on osx. Specifically, I must have it be compioled with `gcc` (instead of the osx default `clang`). Does anyone know how to do this or if this is even possible with conda? Ideally, I would like two separate boost libraries, one compiled with `gcc` and one with `clang`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edited:

Assuming that anaconda is installed in

```
/Users/you/anaconda
```

the following steps should allow you to compile boost with python using gcc compiler bindings for anaconda:

fix anaconda lib:

```
install_name_tool -id /Users/you/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.dylib /Users/you/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
```

(re-)compile boost python

```
mkdir /Users/you/tmp
cd /Users/you/tmp
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.57.0/boost_1_57_0.tar.bz2/download
mv download boost_1_57_0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf boost_1_57_0.tar.bz2
mkdir /Users/you/anaconda_boost_install
cd boost_1_57_0
# export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:  # might be necessary to prevent custom compilers be used
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/Users/you/anaconda_boost_install/ --with-python=/Users/you/anaconda/bin/python2.7
./b2 link=shared
./b2 link=shared install
# source ~/.bashrc  # get back $PATH
```

fix libboost-python against anaconda:

```
install_name_tool -id /Users/you/anaconda_boost_install/lib/libboost_python.dylib /Users/you/anaconda_boost_install/lib/libboost_python.dylib
```

**Note:** gcc compiler is at `/usr/bin/gcc`. 
Uncomment below line to use gcc compiler as default compiler:

```
# export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:  # might be necessary to prevent custom compilers be used
```

You can find the complete tutorial [here](https://github.com/beniz/libcmaes/wiki/Building-libcmaes-on-Mac-OSX#building-with-anaconda-python).